# Left join with multiple conditions asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm stuck on this join code and i need some help.

I'm looking do do this sql statement

```
FROM regSupplier st
LEFT JOIN regSupplierBankAccount sba ON st.nSupplierCode = sba.nSupplierCode AND sba.isDefault = 1
```

but in c# like this

```
FROM st IN dbContext.regSupplier
JOIN sba IN dbContext.regSupplierBankAccount ON NEW {st.nSupplierCode} EQUALS NEW {sba.nSupplierCode, sba.isDefault = 1} INTO joinBank
FROM jb IN joinBank.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

But it does not work.
If anyone can help I appreciate in advance.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expressions used for joining condition in `LINQ` must be equatable. You're trying to compare 2 types of expression that are never equal, so joining will fail.
Actually you need a `where` for the second db set, like this:

```
from st in dbContext.regSupplier
join sba in dbContext.regSupplierBankAccount.Where(e => e.isDefault == 1)
     on st.nSupplierCode equals sba.nSupplierCode into joinBank
from jb in joinBank.DefaultIfEmpty()
```